# create folder inside nsoperation failed

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, create-directory

I use this method inside an NSOperation for check and create a folder:

```
- (void) checkAndCreateFolderWithPath:(NSString *)path {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *pathDaControllare = [[self getLibraryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL isDir;
    BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathDaControllare isDirectory:&isDir];
    if (exists) {
        if (isDir) {

        }
    }
    else {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:pathDaControllare
               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                attributes:nil
                                     error:&error];

        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }

}
```

Using NSOperation I get this error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

if I don't use NSOperation all work perfectly, this is the nsoperation

```
- (void) main {

    NSString *filePath = [fileDict objectForKey:@"url"];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.allmyapp.net/wp-content/iFormulario_Update/%@",filePath];
    urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                               if (data) {

                                   NSString *folderPath = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[filePath lastPathComponent] withString:@""];
                                   [self checkAndCreateFolderWithPath:folderPath];

                                   NSString *pathFile = [[self getLibraryPath] stringByAppendingString:filePath];
                                   [data writeToFile:pathFile atomically:YES];

                                   [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathFile]];

                                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"endFile" object:nil];

                                   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
                                   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

                                   isExecuting = NO;
                                   isFinished = YES;

                                   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
                                   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
                               }
                           }];
}
```

And this the method for create the queue:

```
    for (NSDictionary *dict in fileDaScaricare) {
    DownloadOperation *downloadOperation = [[DownloadOperation alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:downloadOperation];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

    NSString *docFolderPath   =   [stringPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@", self.downloadedFilename]];
[data writeToFile:docFolderPath atomically:YES];
```

It worked for me, and I am able to download a file in MyFolder. Hope it works for you. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: the problem is not the code but the nsoperation, after some test I decide to create the folder before operation start and now work without problem!m!

Comment: When I used the similar thing inside the main() method of nsoperation subclass, it worked well for me. The issue might be due to the directory path. If you still want to try within main(), you can also refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248757/error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-512-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-th